# how can i execute php instructions when closing the browser?

Tags: php, request

I want to execute instructions in the momant of closing the browser, for example the instruction is a requeste sended to update the database?

Comment: php does not know what a browser is

Comment: Considering that PHP runs at the server, it would have no way of telling when the browser closes.  You could try having JavaScript send an AJAX call at that time.  But I honestly don't know if that would even work.

Comment: Without any client-side scripting (i.e. javascript) you would have no hope of doing this.  PHP has no idea what is going on with the client browser.  You would need to listed for browser close event in javascript. Support for this may not be universal, so you would probably be dealing with a fragile operation.  I would suggest rethinking your need for this.

Comment: You could try JavaScript `onbeforeunload` event to detect a moment when user leaves (closes the tab, refreshes the page), so you'd be able to send an AJAX request when event occurs. But it's not like a solid solution to rely on, because it is not really a cross-browser thing with all old browsers support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has nothing to do with the browser. PHP can't interact with it in any way directly, but you can use JavaScript to communicate with your PHP. Doing something when the browser is closed is not always reliable because the browser could close unexpectedly, but you can attempt to gather the info using an `onunload` event listener to send an HTTP request to run your PHP script.

```
window.onunload = function(){
    var xmlhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest)? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    var url = "MyPHPScript.php";
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```